# How to match all C code comments in a file?

Tags: regular-expression, search

I want to match (search) all C code comments in a file in e.g.

```
   enum {
       foo,
       /* Foo is so cool, why can't we all be more like foo? */
       bar,
       /* but bar is mysterious and suave, like the James Bond of enum 
          and variable names. */
       etc,
```

So, I want a regex that will match both the single and multiline C comments delimited by /* and */.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with pure regex based solutions, is that there would be a few false-positives, like in:

```
/*bar*/

char const* p = "/*";

/* bar */

/// foo

char const* e = "*/";
```

`/*` in strings would be matched as well.

I though at first that we could get around it with  [`[*`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%5bstar) and [`]*`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%5dstar), but unfortunately, they are also regex based.

Though, we can have the correct behaviour with `{skip}` parameter in [`search()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#search%28%29)

```
:echo search('/\*\_.\{-}\*/\|//' ,'',0,0, 'synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 0), "name") =~ "\\cstring"')
```

which is best defined as a mapping

```
" for a mapping defined this way, we have to double the '\' before the '|' to express the _or_
nnoremap <silent> [< :<c-u>call search('/\*\_.\{-}\*/\\|//' ,'',0,0, 'synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 0), "name") =~ "\\cstring"')<cr>
```

Comment: Wouldn’t it also be possible to execute a search that only stops on specific highlight groups (eg cComment, or those that match comment case-insensitive)?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble
If we inverse the _skip_ value it may be possible if there aren't any strange side effects on the bordaries of the syntax groups . Also, there are some comments groups "without" _comment_ but doxygen in their name

Comment: Might be worth noting that a relatively recent version of Vim is required to get the skip param. I don't have it in 8.2.486 (my other local build is 8.2.2434 which has it).

Comment: @BLayer My bad. I thought it was older than that.

Answer (score 1):

I already know but I searched the web and couldn't find the definitive answer for VIM (just every other regex language), and I won't remember this again in a week, so I am documenting it here.

And the answer is...

```
/\/\*\_.\{-}\*\/
```

Lemme break it down.

To match the first `\*` you have to escape both the \ and the * so that's `\/\*`

To match the end you have to do the same for `*\` so that's `\*\/` at the end.

You want to include everything between those, this is where it gets tricky. You can use `\_.*` to match everything between (the `\_` makes it multiline), but this is too greedy and will match everything between the first `\*` and the last `*\`.

To make it non-greedy use `\_.\{-}` instead of `\_.*` (`\{-}` uses a "shortest match first" algorithm) and so we get the above vim search regex.

Comment: Can't you do the standard `*?` instead of `{-}`?

Comment: @wizzwizz4, you're confusing with perl. There is no such _standard_ pattern in vim. See [`:h perl-patterns`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#perl%2dpatterns)